# Equation to find the velocity of gas

Tags: thermodynamics, air

Air travels from a hot place to a cold place.

Is there an equation that shows the relation between velocity of gas (specifically air) and difference of temperature between two points?

Comment: Are you sure that air travels as opposed to energy being transferred through collisions between hotter and colder particles?

Comment: Is the air flowing through a tube?

Comment: Yes @Chet Miller

Comment: The product of air density and velocity are constant.  If the pressure is constant, this means that the velocity is proportional to the temperature.